# create a multi-dimensional array in vb.net 2010

Tags: json.net, vb.net-2010

how to create an array that if we convert into json we have the result below.

```
{{"name":"first_example_1"}, {"name": "second_example_1"}}
```

I tried using this

```
dim x as jArray
x.add("first_example_1")
x.add("second_example_1")
```

but when I try to convert the above to json I get this

```
{"firstname_example_1", "second_example_1"}
```

How can I add an index?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        Dim jArray(1) As Object
        jArray(0) = New With {Key .name = "second_example_1"}
        jArray(1) = New With {Key .name = "firstname_example_1"}
        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim result As String
        result = serializer.Serialize(jArray)
```

and don't forget to `Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization`

Comment: I changed my code before I got to read your answer. Based on my question your code works and generate the exact result I want, cool. But I was having hard time de-serializing the object ("due to I'm newbie on VB.net") since I don't have system.web.script.serialization in my reference I don't know why I can't find it on my reference, I only have the system.web.services. Thank you sir. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer of @styx works but I have already change my code. This answer is for additional information only.

I created a class named `PerInfo`

```
public class PerInfo
  public firstname
  public lastname
end class
```

To serialize I wrote this;

```
dim x as new PerInfo
x.firstname = textbox1.text
x.address = textbox2.text

dim res as string =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)
' the above code produces my desired result which is
' {"firstname":"jeo","address":"GSC"}
```

To deserialized I did this;

```
Dim t As PerInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of PerInfo)(x)
'I can now access the `firstname` and `address` via
' t.firstname and t.address

MsgBox(t.firstname & "===" & t.address)
```

Hope this helps...

PS: I manually added via add reference the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` 
version `Net 2.0` for backward compatibility for pc using `.net 2.0` framework if I'm right. Feel free to correct me with this.